# How to pass data to bootstrap modal popup on button click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular12

**Problem Statement:** I've a table with a list of customers record in it. Also, I've one column in my table to delete the customer record. And, When I click on that delete button I display the Bootstrap Modal Pup-up box with 2 options i.e. "Delete" and "Close" as shown in the image below. So, I want to pass customer id to bootstrap model Delete Button so that when I call delete( ) method of my component class that particular customer should get deleted. **So, how can I pass customer id to delete button inside the bootstrap modal?**

**Have a look at below images and HTML Code to understand this better.**

[customer-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xncak.png)

[modal-popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20PTW.png)

```html
<div class="container">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover border">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Mobile No</th>
                <th class="text-center">City</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers$ | async">
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.firstName}} </td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.lastName }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.mobileNo }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.city }}</td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/customer/', customer.mobileNo]" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Edit Customer">
                            <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> <!-- font awesome edit icon -->
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteCustModal">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> <!-- font awesome delete icon -->
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center fw-bold"><a href="#">Generate Invoice</a></td>
                    <td class="text-left fw-bold"><a [routerLink]="['/admin/invoices/', customer.custId]">Invoices</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Delete Customer Confirmation Modal starts here -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteCustModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteCustLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteCustLabel">Delete Customer</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure, you want to delete the customer?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" (click)="delete(31)" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Delete Customer Confirmation Modal ends here -->
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from 'src/app/common/app-error';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-customers',
  templateUrl: './admin-customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-customers.component.css']
})
export class AdminCustomersComponent {
  customers$: Observable<any>;
  error = '';

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {
    this.customers$ = this.customerService.getAll();
  }

  delete(custId: number) {
    this.customerService.delete(custId)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          window.location.reload(); // reload the current page
        },
        (error: AppError) => {
          this.error = error.originalError.message;
          return ;
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable in your `customerService` and use this variable to make process.

For example;

1 - Declare your variable in `customerService`:

```
customerIdToDelete:number = -1;
```

2 - Give a function to your Delete button in Table for changing `customerIdToDelete` in the `customerService`:

```
setCustomerIdToDelete(relatedCustomerId:number) {
this.customerService.customerIdToDelete = relatedCustomerId;
}
```

3 - Now when you clicked the Delete button you have customerId in your `customerService`. Call this data from your pop-up modal.

```
<button type="button" (click)="delete(customerService.customerIdToDelete)" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Delete
                    </button>
```

Comment: **Is it the right way to do this?** Because I've done something similar but inside a Component class instead of a service class. Look at my code below.

Comment: Yes, exactly the same way I think. But I don't know really what is the best practice :) But I am sure that If you need this customerId in another component then you will need service class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, eventually I had to add service class because I later used customerId in another class after I refactored my code a bit in a separate component :-)

Answer (score 0):

**I've achieved this by creating the `setCustomerId(custId: number)` method in a component class as below,**

```
<button type="button" (click)="setCustomerId(customer.custId)" class="btn btn-danger">
     Delete </button>
```

**And, in the bootstrap modal, I simply call delete() method as below,**

```
<button type="button" (click)="delete()" class="btn btn-danger">
       Delete   </button>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from 'src/app/common/app-error';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/model/customer';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-customers',
  templateUrl: './admin-customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-customers.component.css']
})
export class AdminCustomersComponent {
  customerArray: Customer[] = [];
  error = '';
  custId: number;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {
      this.customerService.getAll().subscribe((customer: Customer[]) => this.customerArray = customer);
  }

  setCustomerId(custId: number) {
    this.custId = custId; 
  }

  delete() {
    this.customerService.delete(this.custId)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.custId = undefined; // reset the field
          window.location.reload(); // reload the current page
        },
        (error: AppError) => {
          this.error = error.originalError.message;
          return ;
        });
  }

}
```